# What is meant by "Novelty" in Ubuntu App Contest?

Tags: application-development

There you say "The application must contain exclusively original code and the Participant must be the original author of the content".

So there is a problem,  for example:  When we convert from our program a file using ffmpeg?.

Is that against Novelty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means it should be new in both code and features.  A nice GUI for ffmpeg would certainly be a worthwhile submission, but yet another simple text editor or image viewer probably won't get very high marks from the judges.

Comment: That's what i would like to hear!
I just said ffmpeg for example, i mean generally back-end!
Thanks, i start work right now :)